# fgets reading previous line before input

Tags: c, string, fgets

when I enter an input, the question repeats before i can enter a string.

```
printf("Enter %d coefficients starting from the 0th degree.\nSeparate them by commas: ", degree+1);
fgets(coeffs_string, MAX, stdin);
for(i=0;i<strlen(coeffs_string);i++){
    if(coeffs_string[i]==','){
        commas++;
        continue;
    }
    else if(isdigit(coeffs_string[i]) || coeffs_string[i]==' ')
        continue;
    else{
        printf("\007Error! A character was found during the input!\n");
                coeffs_string[0]='\0';
        commas=0;
        break;
    }
}
```

also, it prints the error handler even when i enter the proper input. I tried using scanf but it just stops. is there a way for fgets or scanf to not quickly read the input? *edit:sorry:i forgot some parts of my code

Comment: what is your input, `ceoffs_string` ? Can you post more complete code?

Comment: *just read the title, so it's a guess:* mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()` ... also the code shown is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try putting a `fflush(stdout);` between your `printf()` and
   `fgets()` statements. Alternatively obtain your input on a separate line from your output.
2. The string returned by `fgets()` will **include** the
   line terminator character/s that the user generated by pushing the enter
   key. You are not explicitly handling these characters so the error message will always be displayed.